# How to apply different functions to a groupby object?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2],
               'min_max': ['max_val', 'max_val', 'min_val', 'min_val', 'max_val', 'max_val', 'min_val', 'min_val'],
               'value': [1, 20, 20, 10, 12, 3, -10, -5 ]})

   id  min_max  value
0   1  max_val      1
1   2  max_val     20
2   1  min_val     20
3   1  min_val     10
4   2  max_val     12
5   1  max_val      3
6   2  min_val    -10
7   2  min_val     -5
```

Each `id` has several maximal and minimal values associated with it. My **desired output** looks like this:

```
    max  min
id          
1     3   10
2    20  -10
```

It contains the maximal `max_val` and the minimal `min_val` for each `id`.

Currently I implement that as follows:

```
gdf = df.groupby(by=['id', 'min_max'])['value']

max_max = gdf.max().loc[:, 'max_val']
min_min = gdf.min().loc[:, 'min_val']

final_df = pd.concat([max_max, min_min], axis=1)
final_df.columns = ['max', 'min']
```

What I don't like is that I have to call `.max()` and `.min()` on the grouped dataframe `gdf`, separately where I throw away 50% of the information (since I am not interested in the maximal `min_val` and the minimal `min_val`).

Is there a way to do this in a more straightforward manner by e.g. passing the function that should be applied to a group directly to the `groupby` call?

EDIT:

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].agg(['max','min'])
```

is not sufficient as there can be the case that a group has a `min_val` that is higher than all `max_val` for that group or a `max_val` that is lower than all `min_val`. Thus, one also has to group based on the column `min_max`.

Result for

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].agg(['max','min'])

    max  min
id          
1    20    1
2    20  -10
```

Result for the code from above:

```
    max  min
id          
1     3   10
2    20  -10
```

Comment: Yes, you are on the good way. Se the answer for the simple solution.

Comment: You can pass a function to the groupby (or rather, as an `agg` call on the groupby), but you'll still get both max and min back for every group.  There's no way to specify a different function depending on the contents of the group, which is what you seem to want.  You could specify a more complicated agg function that would return either the max or min after inspecting the group, but whether that would be "more straightforward" is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Is it possible for there to be a `min_value` for a given group that is higher than all `max_values` (or a max lower than all mins)?  If so, you should maybe update your example data to include such a case.  Without that possibility, there is no difference between picking the maximum `max_value` and just picking the overall max (and likewise for min), so it can be done much more simply, as in quantummind's answer.

Comment: @BrenBarn: Yes, this is possible, that's why I think that one has to groupby also based on `min_max`. Good point. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @Cleb: Don't just say "it works for this example but not generally".  You should *change your sample data* so that the given solution no longer works, so that your sample data actually demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @BrenBarn: I will, just give me a few minutes... (and thanks for the downvote).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slightly tongue-in-cheek solution:

```
>>> df.groupby(['id', 'min_max'])['value'].apply(lambda g: getattr(g, g.name[1][:3])()).unstack()
min_max  max_val  min_val
id                       
1              3       10
2             20      -10
```

This applies a function that grabs the name of the real function to apply from the group key.

Obviously this wouldn't work so simply if there weren't such a simple relationship between the string "max_val" and the function name "max".  It could be generalized by having a dict mapping column values to functions to apply, something like this:

```
func_map = {'min_val': min, 'max_val': max}
df.groupby(['id', 'min_max'])['value'].apply(lambda g: func_map[g.name[1]](g)).unstack()
```

Note that this is slightly less efficient than the version above, since it calls the plain Python max/min rather than the optimized pandas versions.  But if you want a more generalizable solution, that's what you have to do, because there aren't optimized pandas versions of everything.  (This is also more or less why there's no built-in way to do this: for most data, you can't assume a priori that your values can be mapped to meaningful functions, so it doesn't make sense to try to determine the function to apply based on the values themselves.)

Comment: Okay, this made me laugh. :-)

Comment: Works fine, thanks! Could you update your answer where you include such a dictionary?

Comment: Very nice solution, I never seen it before ;) +1

Comment: `getattr(g, g.name[1][:3])()` - this is smart :)

Answer (score 3):

One option is to do the customized aggregation with `groupby.apply`, since it doesn't fit with built in aggregation scenario well:

```
(df.groupby('id')
 .apply(lambda g: pd.Series({'max': g.value[g.min_max == "max_val"].max(), 
                             'min': g.value[g.min_max == "min_val"].min()})))

#    max    min
#id     
# 1    3     10
# 2   20    -10
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks! I upvote it for now and accept it later on depending on other answers' quality.

Answer (score 2):

Solution with [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='id', columns='min_max', values='value', aggfunc=[np.min,np.max])
df1 = df1.loc[:, [('amin','min_val'), ('amax','max_val')]]
df1.columns = df1.columns.droplevel(1)
print (df1)
    amin  amax
id            
1     10     3
2    -10    20
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks! I upvote it for now and accept it later on depending on other answers' quality

Comment: I was thinking of a pivot_table approach too, but the OP seems bothered by the unneeded computation.  I suspect he's spent longer trying to avoid it than he would ever save, so +1.

Comment: This is essentially the same as the OP's solution, which "throws away" the "unnecessary" computation.  But I agree that there's not really anything wrong with doing that "unnecessary" computation in the first place.

Comment: @BrenBarn - yes, you are right, is necessary compute min and max with data which are lost. Thanks for upvote.