# Grouping a data frame by dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with several dates and 2 types of values max values and min values and of course the amount or quantity of the values,it looks like this.

```
Date       Type      Quantity
2008-01-01   Max        100
2008-01-01   Max        105
2008-01-01   Min        80
2008-01-01   Min        75
2009-01-01   Max        101
2009-01-01   Max        106
```

I am trying to group this data frame (I am not sure if grouping is the right term), by day and month (I want to get the maximum and minimum daily value of all years) and also divide it in 2 series max values and min values, so the end result would look like this.
I already eliminate the dates such as 2-29 of the leap years, so this makes sense.

```
Date       Type      Quantity
01-01       Max        106
01-02       Max        107
01-03       Max        104



Date       Type      Quantity
01-01       Min        75
01-02       Min        72
01-03       Min        74
```

Any idea on how to tackle this problem?

Thanks to all!

Comment: Just giving you some feedback.  I'm confused because it seems your input data does not match your output.  I've stopped attempting to answer this question.  Others are still trying to give you an answer.  Hopefully it will be useful to you.  However, for future reference, the quality of the answers you get depends a lot of the quality of the question.  If you put effort into being clear and demonstrating your problem through data and code that you've attempted, you dramatically improve your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: Thanks mate, I will try to be more specific in the data inputs and outputs, I will change it in order to make it simpler!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` by `Series` created by [`strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and column `Type` and aggregate `max` and `min` by `dict` with [super solution of BrenBarn](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42751513/2901002), last for `dfmax` and `dfmin` [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
        Date Type  Quantity
0 2008-01-01  Max       100
1 2008-01-02  Max       105
2 2008-01-01  Min        80
3 2008-01-01  Min        75
4 2009-01-02  Max       101
5 2009-01-01  Max       106
```

```
print (df.Date.dt.strftime('%m-%d'))
0    01-01
1    01-02
2    01-01
3    01-01
4    01-02
5    01-01
Name: Date, dtype: object

func_map = {'Min': min, 'Max': max}
df1 = df.groupby([df.Date.dt.strftime('%m-%d'), 'Type'])['Quantity']
        .apply(lambda g: func_map[g.name[1]](g))
        .reset_index()
print (df1)
    Date Type  Quantity
0  01-01  Max       106
1  01-01  Min        75
2  01-02  Max       105

mask = df1.Type == 'Max'
dfmax = df1[mask]
print (dfmax)
    Date Type  Quantity
0  01-01  Max       106
2  01-02  Max       105

dfmin = df1[~mask]
print (dfmin)
    Date Type  Quantity
1  01-01  Min        75
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this was really helpful!